# Change structure of array to create JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I would like to change structure of my array to produce slightly different JSON file. I tried putting `'category'` into extra array but it doesn't work.

In JSON `'category'` should be in aditional []:

```
"categories": [{
        "category": [{
            "label": "N.12\/02"
        }, {
            "label": "Pn.13\/02"
        }, {
            "label": "Wt.14\/02"
        }, {
            "label": "\u015ar.15\/02"
        }, {
            "label": "Cz.16\/02"
        }, {
            "label": "Pt.17\/02"
        }, {
            "label": "So.18\/02"
        }]
    }],
```

instead of:

```
"categories": {
        "category": [{
            "label": "N.12\/02"
        }, {
            "label": "Pn.13\/02"
        }, {
            "label": "Wt.14\/02"
        }, {
            "label": "\u015ar.15\/02"
        }, {
            "label": "Cz.16\/02"
        }, {
            "label": "Pt.17\/02"
        }, {
            "label": "So.18\/02"
        }]
    },
```

I am using this code to create array and than JSON:

```
$arrData = array(
    "chart" => array(
        "caption" => "Number of visitors last week",
        "subCaption" => "Bakersfield Central vs Los Angeles Topanga",
        "captionFontSize" => "14",
        "subcaptionFontSize" => "14",
        "subcaptionFontBold" => "0",
        "paletteColors" => "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#FF5733,#33B5FF",
        "bgcolor" => "#ffffff",
        "showBorder" => "0",
        "showShadow" => "0",
        "showCanvasBorder" => "0",
        "usePlotGradientColor" => "0",
        "legendBorderAlpha" => "0",
        "legendShadow" => "0",
        "showAxisLines" => "0",
        "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0",
        "divlineThickness" => "1",
        "divLineDashed" => "1",
        "divLineDashLen" => "1",
        "xAxisName" => "Day",
        "showValues" => "0"
    )
);

$actualCategory = array( $rowData[0][1], $rowData[0][2], $rowData[0][3], $rowData[0][4], $rowData[0][5], $rowData[0][6], $rowData[0][7]);
$a = array(
    array( $rowData[2][1], $rowData[2][2], $rowData[2][3], $rowData[2][4], $rowData[2][5], $rowData[2][6], $rowData[2][7]),
    array( $rowData[5][1], $rowData[5][2], $rowData[5][3], $rowData[5][4], $rowData[5][5], $rowData[5][6], $rowData[5][7]),
    array( $rowData[8][1], $rowData[8][2], $rowData[8][3], $rowData[8][4], $rowData[8][5], $rowData[8][6], $rowData[8][7]),
    array( $rowData[11][1], $rowData[11][2], $rowData[11][3], $rowData[11][4], $rowData[11][5], $rowData[11][6], $rowData[11][7])
);


$arrData['categories'] = array( 'category' => array());
foreach ($actualCategory as $value) {
    array_push($arrData['categories']['category'],
        array(
            'label' => $value
        )
    );
}

$arrData['dataset'] = array();

$q = 1;
for($z = 0;$z <= 3; $z++){

    $x[$z] = array('seriesname' => $rowData[$q][0], 'data' => array());
    foreach ($a[$z] as $value) {
        array_push($x[$z]['data'],
            array(
                'value' => $value
            )
        );
    }
    $q = $q + 3;
}
$arrData['dataset'] = $x;
$jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);
```

At this moment I have this output:

```
{"chart":{"caption":"Number of visitors last week","subCaption":"Bakersfield Central vs Los Angeles Topanga","captionFontSize":"14","subcaptionFontSize":"14","subcaptionFontBold":"0","paletteColors":"#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#FF5733,#33B5FF","bgcolor":"#ffffff","showBorder":"0","showShadow":"0","showCanvasBorder":"0","usePlotGradientColor":"0","legendBorderAlpha":"0","legendShadow":"0","showAxisLines":"0","showAlternateHGridColor":"0","divlineThickness":"1","divLineDashed":"1","divLineDashLen":"1","xAxisName":"Day","showValues":"0"},"categories":{"category":[{"label":"N.12\/02"},{"label":"Pn.13\/02"},{"label":"Wt.14\/02"},{"label":"\u015ar.15\/02"},{"label":"Cz.16\/02"},{"label":"Pt.17\/02"},{"label":"So.18\/02"}]},"dataset":[{"seriesname":"IRDN","data":[{"value":"142.59"},{"value":"174.88"},{"value":"176.97"},{"value":"182.48"},{"value":"160.15"},{"value":"160.72"},{"value":"165.47"}]},{"seriesname":"SIRDN","data":[{"value":"148.81"},{"value":"197.29"},{"value":"202.27"},{"value":"211.93"},{"value":"177.87"},{"value":"179.37"},{"value":"177.69"}]},{"seriesname":"IRDN24","data":[{"value":"140.31"},{"value":"174.50"},{"value":"180.38"},{"value":"187.70"},{"value":"161.91"},{"value":"161.62"},{"value":"160.98"}]},{"seriesname":"IRDN 8.22","data":[{"value":"147.33"},{"value":"197.02"},{"value":"202.21"},{"value":"211.28"},{"value":"178.11"},{"value":"179.32"},{"value":"176.31"}]}]}
```

JSON file I need:

```
{"chart":{"caption":"Number of visitors last week","subCaption":"Bakersfield Central vs Los Angeles Topanga","captionFontSize":"14","subcaptionFontSize":"14","subcaptionFontBold":"0","paletteColors":"#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#FF5733,#33B5FF","bgcolor":"#ffffff","showBorder":"0","showShadow":"0","showCanvasBorder":"0","usePlotGradientColor":"0","legendBorderAlpha":"0","legendShadow":"0","showAxisLines":"0","showAlternateHGridColor":"0","divlineThickness":"1","divLineDashed":"1","divLineDashLen":"1","xAxisName":"Day","showValues":"0"},"categories":[{"category":[{"label":"N.12\/02"},{"label":"Pn.13\/02"},{"label":"Wt.14\/02"},{"label":"\u015ar.15\/02"},{"label":"Cz.16\/02"},{"label":"Pt.17\/02"},{"label":"So.18\/02"}]}],"dataset":[{"seriesname":"IRDN","data":[{"value":"142.59"},{"value":"174.88"},{"value":"176.97"},{"value":"182.48"},{"value":"160.15"},{"value":"160.72"},{"value":"165.47"}]},{"seriesname":"SIRDN","data":[{"value":"148.81"},{"value":"197.29"},{"value":"202.27"},{"value":"211.93"},{"value":"177.87"},{"value":"179.37"},{"value":"177.69"}]},{"seriesname":"IRDN24","data":[{"value":"140.31"},{"value":"174.50"},{"value":"180.38"},{"value":"187.70"},{"value":"161.91"},{"value":"161.62"},{"value":"160.98"}]},{"seriesname":"IRDN 8.22","data":[{"value":"147.33"},{"value":"197.02"},{"value":"202.21"},{"value":"211.28"},{"value":"178.11"},{"value":"179.32"},{"value":"176.31"}]}]}
```

Dump of my array:

```
array(3) { ["chart"]=> array(20) { ["caption"]=> string(28) "Number of visitors last week" ["subCaption"]=> string(42) "Bakersfield Central vs Los Angeles Topanga" ["captionFontSize"]=> string(2) "14" ["subcaptionFontSize"]=> string(2) "14" ["subcaptionFontBold"]=> string(1) "0" ["paletteColors"]=> string(31) "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#FF5733,#33B5FF" ["bgcolor"]=> string(7) "#ffffff" ["showBorder"]=> string(1) "0" ["showShadow"]=> string(1) "0" ["showCanvasBorder"]=> string(1) "0" ["usePlotGradientColor"]=> string(1) "0" ["legendBorderAlpha"]=> string(1) "0" ["legendShadow"]=> string(1) "0" ["showAxisLines"]=> string(1) "0" ["showAlternateHGridColor"]=> string(1) "0" ["divlineThickness"]=> string(1) "1" ["divLineDashed"]=> string(1) "1" ["divLineDashLen"]=> string(1) "1" ["xAxisName"]=> string(3) "Day" ["showValues"]=> string(1) "0" } ["categories"]=> array(1) { ["category"]=> array(7) { [0]=> array(1) { ["label"]=> string(80) " N. 12/02 " } [1]=> array(1) { ["label"]=> string(81) " Pn. 13/02 " } [2]=> array(1) { ["label"]=> string(81) " Wt. 14/02 " } [3]=> array(1) { ["label"]=> string(82) " Śr. 15/02 " } [4]=> array(1) { ["label"]=> string(81) " Cz. 16/02 " } [5]=> array(1) { ["label"]=> string(81) " Pt. 17/02 " } [6]=> array(1) { ["label"]=> string(81) " So. 18/02 " } } } ["dataset"]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { ["seriesname"]=> string(34) " IRDN " ["data"]=> array(7) { [0]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(43) " 142.59 " } [1]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(43) " 174.88 " } [2]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(43) " 176.97 " } [3]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(43) " 182.48 " } [4]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(43) " 160.15 " } [5]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(43) " 160.72 " } [6]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(43) " 165.47 " } } } [1]=> array(2) { ["seriesname"]=> string(80) " SIRDN " ["data"]=> array(7) { [0]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(61) " 148.81 " } [1]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(61) " 197.29 " } [2]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(61) " 202.27 " } [3]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(61) " 211.93 " } [4]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(61) " 177.87 " } [5]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(61) " 179.37 " } [6]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(61) " 177.69 " } } } [2]=> array(2) { ["seriesname"]=> string(74) " IRDN24 " ["data"]=> array(7) { [0]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(60) " 140.31 " } [1]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(60) " 174.50 " } [2]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(60) " 180.38 " } [3]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(60) " 187.70 " } [4]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(60) " 161.91 " } [5]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(60) " 161.62 " } [6]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(60) " 160.98 " } } } [3]=> array(2) { ["seriesname"]=> string(112) " IRDN 8.22 " ["data"]=> array(7) { [0]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(69) " 147.33 " } [1]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(69) " 197.02 " } [2]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(69) " 202.21 " } [3]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(69) " 211.28 " } [4]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(69) " 178.11 " } [5]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(69) " 179.32 " } [6]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(69) " 176.31 " } } } } }
```

My question is how to change my code do this?

Comment: Please post the dump of $arrData.

Comment: @sajushko What is a dump?

Comment: output of var_dump($arrData)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
$arrData['categories'] = array( array ('category' => array()));
```

instead of

```
$arrData['categories'] = array( 'category' => array());
```

It will works as you want to.